# I have two tables with common Quote_No and I need to sum Qty in Quote_Items with Required by Date in Table Quotes

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to get the sum of "Qty" in a Table A called "Quote_Items" based on a "Required_by_Date" from Table B called Quotes. Both tables have a common "Quote_No" The required date is one month ago.

I have used the following but it produces a NULL, but I cannot see why

```
select sum(Qty) 
from quotes.Quote_Items_Quantities 
      left outer join quotes.Quotes on (Quote_Required_by_Date = Qty)
WHERE (DatePart(yy, Quote_Required_by_Date) = DatePart(yy, DateAdd(m,1,getdate()))) and
      datepart(m,Quote_Required_by_Date) = datepart(m,dateadd(m,1,getdate()))
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: if both table have the same data then try using the inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(i.Qty)
FROM Quote_Items i
JOIN Quotes q on i.Quote_No = q.Quote_No
AND CONVERT(varchar, q.Required_by_Date, 112) = CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()), 112)
```

or this (equivalent without using JOIN)

```
SELECT SUM(i.Qty)
FROM Quote_Items i
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Quotes WHERE Quote_No = i.Quote_No AND CONVERT(varchar, Required_by_Date, 112) = CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()), 112))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is producing `NULL` because of the `join` condition.  You have

```
on Quote_Required_by_Date = Qty
```

However, the date is not going to match the quantity.  Instead, you need to match on the `Quote_No`, according to your question:

```
select sum(Qty) 
from quotes.Quote_Items_Quantities qiq left outer join
     quotes.Quotes q
     on q.Quote_Required_by_Date = qiq.Qty
WHERE (DatePart(yy, Quote_Required_by_Date) = DatePart(yy, DateAdd(m,1,getdate()))) and
      datepart(m,Quote_Required_by_Date) = datepart(m,dateadd(m,1,getdate()));
```

You can also simplify your query by using the `month()` and `year()` functions:

```
select sum(Qty) 
from quotes.Quote_Items_Quantities qiq left outer join
     quotes.Quotes q
     on q.Quote_Required_by_Date = qiq.Qty
WHERE year(Quote_Required_by_Date) = year(DateAdd(m, 1, getdate()) and
      month(Quote_Required_by_Date) = month(dateadd(m,1,getdate());
```

Finally, you mind find it useful to use `group by` and get the results for many months:

```
select year(Quote_Required_by_Date), month(Quote_Required_by_Date), sum(Qty)
from quotes.Quote_Items_Quantities qiq left outer join
     quotes.Quotes q
     on q.Quote_Required_by_Date = qiq.Qty
group by year(Quote_Required_by_Date), month(Quote_Required_by_Date)
order by 1 desc, 2 desc;
```

Comment: Gordon, Thank you for your quick feedback. Your first two suggestions still provide a NULL answer and your third suggestion produces the following error

Comment: Gordon, The third suggestion produces Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'quotes.Quotes.Quote_Required_by_Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.